# IF i want to write an episode to a TV sitcom, how can i send it to the TV network?

Tags: publishing, process

what are the steps to such thing, i want to write an episode to beavis and butthead and send it to MTV ,i don't live in the USA,i don't know if that a problem , please provide me with all the details that can help.

Comment: Well, your first problem is that *Beavis and Butthead* hasn't been on the air for over a decade.

Comment: there is a new season on mtv produced in 2011,update yourself please.

Comment: People, let's keep this civil. XNA, no offense intended, but perhaps you might consider learning to write in complete sentences with proper punctuation and capitalization. A writer who can't (or isn't) writing in standard English will be rejected out of hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't work in the TV industry, as I understand it, most shows have their own stable of writers and generally don't accept unsolicited manuscripts. (Some of the Star Trek shows did, but I gathered that was unusual.)

At the very least, if you do want to write for a show which does accept outside manuscripts (and I don't know of any), you would need to get an agent to submit it for you. Even a show which does take manuscripts from out-of-house writers is not going to take one without representation.

ETA References. The upshot is "it's extremely probable that you need an agent, but there's an outside chance you can get by without one."

[How do I submit my scripts to TV Shows?](http://www.scriptmag.com/features/primetime-how-do-i-submit-my-scripts-to-tv-shows)

[Writer's Guild of America](http://www.tvwritersvault.com/tvspecscripts/tvspecscripts.asp): *Companies with episodic television shows and once-per-week serials must hire freelance writers each season for each series, depending on their network order,* but it explicitly says you must have spec scripts for an *agent* to submit. A lot of good instruction at this link.

[What's the Process for Submitting a TV Script?](http://ask.metafilter.com/39564/Whats-the-process-for-submitting-a-tv-script)

[About.com:](http://animatedtv.about.com/cs/groening/ht/htwritescript.htm) "You must secure an agent to be considered a professional writer."

[Two references](http://scriptangel.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/i%E2%80%99ve-written-a-script-what-next-part-two/) for companies which will apparently take unsolicited scripts without an agent, in the UK.

[Do I need an agent?](http://www.screenwritingforhollywood.com/film-forum/do-i-need-an-agent)

Comment: >is not going to take one without representation - Says who?

Comment: As I said, I don't work in the TV industry, so I'm quite happy to be proven wrong. But I've been reading about it extensively for years, including a lot of behind-the-scenes interviews, and that's the impression I have. If you know otherwise, by all means answer with actual evidence.

Comment: Well, honestly, "actual evidence" is the thing I wanted from you ;) - I know this "you need an agent" argument from the fiction publishing world, and I only need a link to D. W. Smith to prove it wrong. So I doubt it is true for TV manuscripts either. But I do not know, that's why I asked for a reference.

Comment: Fair enough. I will edit to reflect references. Let me know if those are sufficient. :)

Comment: Oh dear, looks like I'll keep writing novels ;)